# Java standard crypto API vs. specific provider (Bouncy Castle)

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle, cryptoapi

I'm developing a java application that uses some basic/common crypto (AES, 3DES, DH, ECDH) and is supposed to run on as many platforms (mainly Win/Linux/Android) as possible. Concerning the crypto part I thought it would be best to use the standard Java API so users can use whatever cryptographic provider they desire.

Luckily/Unfortunately I inherited some old code fixed to Bouncy Castle.
Now I have to decide between either giving up my idea of staying independent of any crypto provider or updating/rewriting the old code to work with the standard API. The amount of work for updating/rewriting would be feasible but is it worth the while?

Comment: There is [Spongy Castle](http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/) for Android which is essentially a renamed Bouncy Castle. It has [issues on desktop Java](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/issues/13) while the original [Bouncy Castle has issues with Android](http://www.unwesen.de/2011/06/12/encryption-on-android-bouncycastle/)

Comment: @zapl Android already uses a custom version of Bouncy Castle provider.

Comment: @MisterSmith that's what the 2nd link explains: the shipped Bouncy castle can have no AES and Android can override your attempts to ship a full version of BouncyCastle since it detects it as existing. SpongyCastle renames everything to prevent that optimization and allows you to make sure that you have AES.

Comment: @zapl Well I've used full AES-256 with built-in Android provider, unlike Java SE which is restricted to 128 by default.

Comment: @MisterSmith The encryption algorithms provided through the standard API depend on what is installed on the device. Each device can potentially have a different set. E.g. older devices [don't support ECDH](http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2011/12/using-ecdh-on-android.html). And even older had [no Blowfish](http://b.android.com/9313). If you want to be compatible with all of them you'll have to ship an implementation. I didn't find any further proof that that devices exist without AES but I would assume that it is possible.